# How to get value of action class variable inside script tag in jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, action

I have used a variable in action class as shown below

```
public class MyAction {
  private String str;
   .............

  public String getStr() {
    return str;
   }

  public void setStr(String str) {
    this.str = str;
   }
}
```

I have used value of this variable in my jsp page inside script tag in body tag.

```
<body>
   .............
   <script>
       var strng = <s:property value="str"/>;
       ...........
   </script>
</body>
```

It doesn't receive any value, but when `str` variable in action class is declared as `public`, then value of `str` variable from action class is obtained.
But, i want to keep `str` variable private. What should i do?

Comment: Try this <s:property value="${str}"/>

Comment: I do believe this is not possible.  I think you can only get public attributes in the jsp.

Comment: This should work just fine.

Comment: You probably have a typo in the getter (the real one, not the one posted here). Check it carefully.

Comment: Agreed, there's no real issue with the JSP itself. There *is*, however, an issue if it's actually a string, because you need to quote it in the JS, and JS-escape it. Check your JS console.

Comment: Andrea Ligios, I have checked there is no typing error in getter & setter.

Comment: You can use EL. Your EL would be something like this '${myAction.str}'.

Comment: [Sudarshan_SMD](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1969874/sudarshan-smd), I have also tried '${myAction.str}', but same problem is occurring. Is it necessary to keep 'str' variable 'public' to get its value in jsp page?